# Mongo query is running endlessly

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Something went wrong and I don't understand why. I have a script that used to be working but all of the sudden if just stopped. It's basically a mongo query on a big Mongo collection (600gb+).

Here's the query:

```
db.action_traces.findOne( {"block_time": {"$lt": "2018-07-15T00:00:00.000Z"} } ).pretty()
```

Originally I wasn't using findOne but I've restricted the results to one just in case I could help but the result is the same: nothing happens.

If I just run a `find` query it goes fine.

There is nothing showing up in the mongodb log and nothing seems relevant in the syslog either.

There is clearly something wrong with Mongo though, as htop is showing me this:

[image: Htop mongodb]

The mongo process is fluctuating but is most of the time filling out one CPU thread to 100%.

Can anyone help?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like its probably trawling through the whole collection - have you added an index on `block_time` ?

`.find()` returns a cursor pointing to the first set of matching documents, ordered by default (natural order) if you dont specify a sort order.

`.findOne()` returns a single document - with the provisio that if your query matches multiple documents then it uses their "natural order" and returns the first one (implying that it needs to find all matches first).

I'm guessing that your collection needs an index on that field - meaning it can look up the result without a full scan.

Comment: Awesome! That actually worked, many thanks for helping me understand how the cogs work in the background so I won't get stuck again ;-)

Comment: Actually... side question, I'm running: `db.action_traces.deleteMany({ "block_time": { "$lt": "2018-10-28T00:00:00.000Z" } }, {w: "majority", wtimeout: 60000})` but 1/ it runs infinitely and 2/ it never times out Any idea why? Of course I've checkd with a find query and there are some `block_time` with a date older than the one in the query.

Comment: Sounds like the operation is too big for the server to handle. You can try running multiple deletes of smaller sections of the data or (probably neater) write a script that fetches batches of ids of records matching your query, and then delete them by Id. Then just let that script run in a loop until no ids get returned.

Comment: I have also read about people copying records they want to keep into a new collection and then dropping the old one - might be faster if you are going to delete most of the data.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm also leaning toward the "too big for the server to handle" side as well... Actually new issue this morning, the collection is still 645gb but no data seem to be there, even if I'm running  `db.action_traces.find().pretty())` I don't get a single document back (and the query runs fine without anything in the logs)... What a mess this is lol, any ideas?

Comment: Just in case, I've run a `db.action_traces.stats()` and it's not empty, it does tell me that `"count" : 1758603988` and `"size" : NumberLong("2006928344462")`. I'm so confused, any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Afraid I'm not too sure there - you should ask a new question with as much detail as possible and I'm sure one of the mongo pros out there will have some ideas. (Also, stackoverflow doesnt like long Q&A threads...)